# Duvida com coluna Banco

Tags: mysql

Recebi um dump do mysql para estudo e fiquei com duvida em certa coluna texto com os campos preenchidos dessa forma:

```
'a:5:{
    s:9:\"user_data\";
    s:0:\"\";
    s:4:\"nome\";
    s:5:\"admin\";
    s:2:\"id\";
    s:1:\"1\";
    s:9:\"permissao\";
    s:1:\"1\";
    s:6:\"logado\";
    b:1;
}'
```

a coluna em sim continha esse nome `user_data` . Poderiam me ajudar com essa duvida de conhecimento. Infelizmente não tenho o código do sistema. Em outra tabela tbm contem uma coluna assim mas com coluna de nome permissões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este formato de dados é gerado pelo `serialize` do php, ele é usado pra converter variáveis php e um formato que possa ser armazedo, principalmente *arrays*.

Quando faz isto:

```
<?php
$data = array(
   'nome' => 'Thalles',
   'hobby' => 'Programar'
);

echo serialize($data);
```

É gerado esta `string`:

> a:2:{s:4:"nome";s:7:"Thalles";s:5:"hobby";s:9:"Programar";}

Então você pode armazenar em um banco de dados ou .txt e recupera-lo depois, no entanto vai ser necessário usar o `unserialize` pra decodificar, por exemplo:

*salvar.php*

```
<?php
$data = array(
   'nome' => 'Thalles',
   'hobby' => 'Programar'
);

file_put_contents('data.txt', serialize($data));
```

*ler.php*

```
<?php
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('data.txt'));//Trás de volta o array

print_r($data);
```

Desta maneira você pode armazenar vários dados em uma coluna só no seu banco, o wordpress usa esta técnica pra facilitar a criação customizada de plugins e banners.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação. Adicionando serialize nos estudos :)